# which VS code version is required

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi I am a novice in his field and want to motivate my kids to learn this highly valuable skill, have enrolled in CS50s web programing  with python and java Script 2020 course.

BRIAN YU the speaker is using Microsoft's Visual Studio Code; I too downloaded this from net but the page displaying on my screen is different from Braian Yu, can someone guide me to the correct VS code and how to download.

Comment: Please post comparison screenshots.

Comment: There is only one version of Visual Studio Code (that simplicity part of why it's so popular), but it's _evergreen software_ that receives major feature updates every few months, and the UI is also very customizable (e.g. different theming).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the differences at this point - it's like if I wanted to drive the exact same Blue 2018 Ford Focus that my driving instructor drives but all I can get is a Red 2020 Ford Focus. Whatever the differences are at this point, they're minor - and every beginner JS tutorial usually starts in Notepad, not an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://code.visualstudio.com/Download
Download according to your system(windows, mac or linux)
After downloading whenever you connect to internet v.s. code will look for updates and automatically will get updated.
The difference in vscode maybe because your speaker has installed some extensions.
You can download extensions direct from vscode or from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/
Some common extensions are

1. Live server
2. Prettier
3. Emmet
4. Vscode material theme
5. Es lint , etc, etc
   If you further need any help you can comment below and ask me